# Error when implementing FGSM in Keras with Cleverhans

Tags: cleverhans

I'm trying to generate adversarial examples using the Cleverhans (FGSM) tutorials with `Keras`, but so far I have been unsuccessful. I'm using a the keras generator functionality to retrieve dataset images.(Python 3.7)

I'm fairly new at working with `Cleverhans` and I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I'm following the Cleverhans Mnist tutorial so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import os
from cleverhans.cleverhans.utils_tf import model_eval
#from cleverhans.utils_tf import model_train
from cleverhans.cleverhans.utils import AccuracyReport
report = AccuracyReport()
batch_size = 1


path = "/home/Downloads/dataset/"
path_test = os.path.join(path, "test/")
path_train = os.path.join(path, "train/")

# create a data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

# load and iterate test dataset
itr = test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(path_test, target_size=(150, 150), class_mode='categorical', batch_size=1)
itr2 = train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(path_train, target_size=(150, 150), class_mode='categorical', batch_size=1)
X, Y = itr.next()
W, Z = itr2.next()


###############################################################################
# create tensorflow session
sess = tf.Session()

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

K.set_session(sess)

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('/home/saved_models/model.100.h5')

from cleverhans.cleverhans.utils_keras import KerasModelWrapper
wrap = KerasModelWrapper(model)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 150, 150, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 2))

from cleverhans.cleverhans.attacks import FastGradientMethod
fgsm = FastGradientMethod(wrap, sess=sess)

fgsm_params = {'eps': .007,'clip_min': -1.,'clip_max': 1.}
adv_x = fgsm.generate(x, **fgsm_params)
adv_x = tf.stop_gradient(adv_x)
adv_prob = model(adv_x)

# Evaluate the accuracy of the model on adversarial examples
eval_par = {'batch_size': batch_size}
acc = model_eval(sess, x, y, adv_prob, X_test=X, Y_test=Y, args=eval_par)
print('Test accuracy on adversarial examples: %0.4f\n' % acc)
report.clean_train_adv_eval = acc

# Calculating train error
eval_par = {'batch_size': batch_size}
acc = model_eval(sess, x, y, adv_prob, X, Y, args=eval_par)
report.train_clean_train_adv_eval = acc
```

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
>     (0) Invalid argument: assertion failed: [] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:x (Placeholder_539:0) = ] [[[[-59.939003 -72.779 -79.68]]]...] [y (Cast/x:0) = ] [-1]
>        [[node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert (defined at /home/Downloads/cleverhans/cleverhans/utils_tf.py:749) ]]
>     (1) Invalid argument: assertion failed: [] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:x (Placeholder_539:0) = ] [[[[-59.939003 -72.779 -79.68]]]...] [y (Cast/x:0) = ] [-1]
>        [[node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert (defined at /home/Downloads/cleverhans/cleverhans/utils_tf.py:749) ]]
>        [[GroupCrossDeviceControlEdges_0/model_1_1/conv1_pad/Pad/_3698]]
>   0 successful operations.
>   0 derived errors ignored.